# Why should I use portable class libraries with Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, .net, dll, xamarin

I am currently evaluating Xamarin for my company with the goal to develop iOS and later on maybe Android applications. (Windows Phone or Windows store apps are not a concern for us). We are thinking of putting shared functionality into a common library and according to the Xamarin Docs PCLs are the way to go. However why can’t I just create normal .net class libraries and reference against them?

Mono serves as the base for Xamarin and has in most areas a quite mature implementation of .net Framework which should be both available on Android and on iOS since it is part of Xamarin.
Am I missing some important fact or are PCLs only needed when I also want to develop Windows Store applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular .NET libraries support a single target framework.  The .NET framework used by Xamarin iOS is not the same as the one used by Xamarin Android, or Windows Phone, etc.  They all use different subsets and variations of the "full" framework.  So a dll compiled against one flavor of the framework will not work with a different target.

PCLs avoid this by allowing you to target multiple frameworks and use the intersection of functions that they all support.

Comment: Thank you that makes it much clearer. I was not aware that BCLs differed between Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Answer (score 0):

PCLs are one of the two ways of sharing code between platform-specific projects in Xamarin (the other being Shared Projects). They allow you to target multiple platforms, but you end up working with a smaller set of assemblies.

Comment: Check out Jason Smith's (Xamarin.Forms lead) recent tweet and subsequent replies: https://twitter.com/jassmith87/status/529785150842748930